# discord.py: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elyes\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\disnake\ui\modal.py", line 229, in _scheduled_task
    await self.callback(interaction)
  File "d:\Workspaces\Python Workspaces\Discord Bots\JustMe Bot\bot.py", line 143, in callback
    print(user.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name
```

I don't know why this error shows, because it doesn't make any sense.
I've tried to change the `disnake.utils.get` function, but it doesn't work.

```py
# The callback received when the user input is completed.
    async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
        # Get the input from the modal
        for key, value in inter.text_values.items():
            # get user by name
            if key == "name":
                # split value by #
                username, discriminator = value.split("#")
                user = disnake.utils.get(inter.channel.guild.members, name=username, discriminator=discriminator)
                print(user.name)
```

Comment: It probably failed to find the member. Are you sure they exist? Is the case sensitivity right?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to documentation https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils#disnake.utils.get

It clearly states: `If nothing matching the passed attributes is found, None is returned.`

When there are no results of getting a value in an iterable sequence `disnake.utils.get` put the value None in the `user` variable